# Multiple features into one using Pipeline and featureUnion from Python Scikit-learn

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, feature-extraction

I would like to train and predict the gender of a person. I have two features 'name' and 'randint' each coming from a different Pandas column. I am trying to **1)** combine them into a pipeline/featureunion. As well as **2)** adding the predicted label onto the original pandas data frame. Though I am getting the error for the former objective 1):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
import numpy as np

clf = make_pipeline(CountVectorizer(), LogisticRegressionCV(cv=2))

data = {
    'Bruce Lee': 'Male',
    'Bruce Banner': 'Male',
    'Peter Parker': 'Male',
    'Peter Poker': 'Male',
    'Peter Springsteen': 'Male',
    'Bruce Willis': 'Male',
    'Sarah McLaughlin': 'Female',
    'Sarah Silverman': 'Female',
    'Sarah Palin': 'Female',
    'Sarah Hyland': 'Female',
    'Bruce Li': 'Male',
    'Bruce Milk': 'Male',
    'Bruce Springsteen': 'Male',
    'Bruce Willis': 'Male',
    'Sally Juice': 'Female',
    'Sarah Silverwoman': 'Female',
    'Sarah Palin': 'Female',
    'Sarah Hyland': 'Female',
    'Bruce Paul': 'Male',
    'Bruce Lame': 'Male',
    'Bruce Springsteen': 'Male',
    'Bruce Willis': 'Male',
    'Sarah Willis': 'Female',
    'Sarah Goldman': 'Female',
    'Sarah Palin': 'Female',
    'Sally Hyland': 'Female',
    'Bruce McDonald': 'Male',
    'Bruce Lane': 'Male',
    'Peter Springsteen': 'Male',
    'Bruce Willis': 'Male',
    'Sarah McLaughlin': 'Female',
    'Sarah Goldwoman': 'Female',
    'Sarah Palin': 'Female',
    'Sarah Hylie': 'Female'
    }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns = ['name', 'gender']
df['randomInt'] = np.random.choice(range(1, 6), df.shape[0])

class ExtractNames(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X, *args):
        return [{'first': name.split()[0],
                 'last': name.split()[-1]}
                for name in X]

    def fit(self, *args):
        return self

class ExtractRandInt(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X2, *args):
        return [{'randInt': num} for num in X2]

    def fit(self, *args):
        return self   

trans = ExtractNames()
trans2 = ExtractRandInt()
Combined = FeatureUnion([trans, trans2])

clf = make_pipeline(Combined(), DictVectorizer(), LogisticRegressionCV())
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, train_size=0.5, random_state=68)
clf.fit(df_train['name'], df_train['randomInt'], df_train['gender'])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\test5.py", line 74, in <module>
    clf = make_pipeline(Combined(), DictVectorizer(), LogisticRegressionCV())
TypeError: 'FeatureUnion' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call () on Combined object (You can call it on Classes because it's their constructor, but in Combined object you don't have `__call__` method) so that line must be:

```
clf = make_pipeline(Combined, DictVectorizer(), LogisticRegressionCV())
```

Comment: When I remove the '()' from Combined, it gives me a new error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KubiK\Desktop\test5.py", line 76, in <module>
    clf.fit(df_train['name'], df_train['randomInt'], df_train['gender'])
TypeError: fit() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Comment: The reason why I return everything as a dictionary is because I need to do a DictVectorizer() function, that's why I need a dict input, am I right?

Comment: You need to call fit with two parameters. If you want to use DictVectorizer on output of some transformer which returns dict - you should do this after transformer, not after FeatureUnion. Because FeatureUnion don't know how to combine two columns of dicts into one.